# insert multiple rows that have same foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an association table named studentClasses that has 2 columns (student_id, classe_id).

I have insert multiple rows for one student like that

`INSERT INTO studentClasses(student_id, classe_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,5);`

and with sequelize I did

`const studentClasse = await StudentClasse.bulkCreate([{ student_id:1,classe_id:1},{student_id:1,classe_id:2},...,{ student_id:1,classe_id:5}]);`

these 2 statements have a duplicate of student_id foreign key.

so, is there an ather way to insert multiple rows without make a duplication of  student_id?.

i-e. we write only once student_id and we write the other values of classe_id.

can we do that with sequelize using bulkCreate?.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you shoudl not use it

Comment: Whats wrong with what you are doing, look perfect to me